# Passing Scroll event to another view

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, touch-event

**The Objective:**
I am writing a view that behaves like a RecyclerView inside the ViewPager i-e; The view moves when the finger is moved horizontally and RecyclerView scrolls when the finger is moved vertically. Please note that my custom view has another objective while the finger is moving horizontally, so therefore I can't use viewpager here.

**The Problem:**
The overlay view handles the horizontal finger motion movement properly, however the vertical event when passed down to the RecyclerView doesn't result in scrolling.

**The Question:**
What should I do that the vertical finger movement is passed to the RecyclerView and result in Scrolling?

**The Code:**

```
mOverlayView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        //some code
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mBackupTouchDownEvent = event;
                        // some code
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            // some logic {

                                movingHorizontally = true;
                            }

                            return true;
                        } else
                            movingHorizontally = false;
                        break;
                }

                // executor came down here? This means finger moved vertically
                mRecyclerView.requestFocus();
                mRecyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(mBackupTouchDownEvent); // don't cause scrolling
                mRecyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(event); // don't cause scrolling? Alternative solutoin?
                return false;
}
```

*XML:*

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#77555555"
            android:id="@+id/overlayScreen"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```